# domain name does not open the website, redirects to default IP instead of opening www

Tags: web, dns, hosting, windows-server-2003, webmail

I recently changed NS of one domain to another host and created a domain using Helm Control Panel.

The problem is that when I type domain name (ie. www.MyDomain.com) instead of opening the coresponding website, it opens host webmail page which is served by smarter mail.

I have cleared dns cache, rebuilt and updated it. also I removed the domain and added it again.

Pinging the domain name returns server's IP address and it's up.
The hosting OS is windows server 2003.

I appreciate any comments to solve the problem.

Edit 1:

Though this was a long last headache, I solved the problem by **removing domain's DNS entry alongside with all alias domains attached to it directly in DNS Server console**, restarting server and then rebuilding DNS Zone via Helm Control Panel. I'm not sure if this was the best practice but it seems there was a mix of domain's DNS, alias domains' DNS, Hosting software, Caching problems.

Edit 2:

Actually this error was not about the DNS stuff, it is a **failure of Helm Control Panel adding/removing alias domains**. To share the experience, I Add a answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a DNS error.

I found the answer when examining IIS where i noticed the website was stopped.

Forcing the website to start, this error message poped up:

**IIS was unable to start the site, another site may already be using the port you configured for this site.**

Further investigation revealed that one same domain alias has previously added to another domain/host.

Removing this alias from IIS > Website Properties > Website > Advanced > Advanced Website Identification, fixed the problem.

What led me to assume a dns problem mistakenly was that default IP of server is set to mail server by default. so, when a website is stopped the domain points to mail server.

Hope this help for future.